# Having models' declarations at two folders in Django

Tags: python, django, import, models

**How can you have model declarations at two different directories in Django?**

I have the model at the directory **Code** which contains "**init**.py", "models.py" and "admin.py".
It is working properly alone.

I want to have the directory **History** which has the model of the revisions of the given questions. I have the similar files in the directory.

I need to tell Django to use the model at the directory "History" somehow, since I have a ManyToMany relation in the table Questions to the other directory.

I get the following import error

```
ImportError at /

cannot import name history

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Exception Type:     ImportError
Exception Value:    

cannot import name history

Exception Location:     /home/noa/build/CML/../CML/codes/models.py in <module>, line 2
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.2
Python Path:    ['/home/noa/build/CML', '/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/var/lib/python-support/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/gtk-2.0', '/var/lib/python-support/python2.6/pyinotify', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 11 Dec 2009 15:46:30 -0600
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sounds like both of your directories are Django apps, and assuming you've put both of them in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py` you can refer to them using a string without having to import:

```
# in code/models.py

class Questions(models.Model):
    histories = models.ManyToManyField('history.MyHistoryModel')
```

Note that the path is case sensitive... so if you app is truly called 'History' you will need to reference it using 'History.MyHistoryModel'.

Comment: What is "MyHistoryModel"? I have the file history/models.py. How can you know what is the variable based on the file?

Comment: It's not a variable... it's just an example of a string literal meant to be replaced by whatever the model class in history/models.py is actually called (you mention a directory called 'History', but didn't actually put in the name of the model, so I'm using a placeholder).

Answer (score 0):

Generally people just have one "models" directory, or even sometimes just one models file. If you get to the point that you feel you need 2 full directories for your models, it's probably better to start thinking about breaking your one app, into a couple of small apps instead generally. That being said, there's a number of things that could be potentially wrong just with your setup that we can't see.

Anytime I have an import error though, I drop to a python shell and try to import the item. If it fails, then something is either wrong with the module (you'd be surprised how often I forget __init__.py), or it's not properly in your python path.

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is called History, you should change `import history` to `import History`, as python imports are case-sensitive (on my Linux box, at least).